# How to dynamically create object from collection based on custom attribute?

Tags: c#

I have to create dynamic objects from object collection based on the custom attributes.

```
public class Customer
{
    [AccountAttribute(name: "CustomerAccountID")]        
    public int CustomerID { get; set; } 

    [RoleAttribute(name: "RoleUserID")]
    [AccountAttribute(name: "AccountRole")]        
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
```

}

I have a list of Customer data

var custData= GetCustomerData();

I want to filter the the Customer collection based on the attribute.

If I am filtering based on AccountAttribute, I am  expecting list of CustomerID and RoleID and in the newly created list property name should be CustomerAccountID, AccountRole.

If filtering based on RoleAttribute, only RoleID is expecting and field name should be RoleUserID.

The above class is just an example, more than 20 fields are available and has three different attributes.

Some fields belongs to single attribute, but some belongs to multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create dynamic objects when you don't know the property names at compile time is the `ExpandoObject` - it lets you access the object using the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface, so all you need to do is add the appropriate key-value pairs:

```
private static dynamic CustomerToCustomObject<TAttribute>(Customer customer) 
    where TAttribute : BaseAttribute // assuming the Name property is on a base class for all attributes
{
    dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
    var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;

    var propertiesToInclude = typeof(Customer).GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Any());
    foreach (var property in propertiesToInclude)
    {
        var attribute = (BaseAttribute)(property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Single());
        dictionary.Add(attribute.Name, property.GetValue(customer));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks.. With some minor modification I was able to use this code.